# Android, anisotropic filtering?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm just learning OpenGL ES on Android, and I am trying to get some kind of **anisotropic filtering** on textures. I want to increase the size of a sprite, with some kind of interpolation, instead of this "nearest-pixel-interpolation".

Is there anything like this in the OpenGL ES standard or do I have to make one texture for each size?

Comment: Do you want actual anisotropic filtering, or just `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR`?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This seemed to be the best way to do a simple mipmap.

http://insanitydesign.com/wp/2009/08/01/android-opengl-es-mipmaps/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe.  Check your [extension string](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/texture_filter_anisotropic.txt).

Comment: I can't find a flag called TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, if that is what I'm supposed to look for.

Comment: You're supposed to call [`glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glGetString.xml) and make sure `GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic` is in the list before using the new tokens/functions in the extension document.